# Barplot using Lattice Package for VADeaths inbuilt dataset

Tags: r, lattice

I am currently doing R visualization in Katakoda training. And i am stuck
with one question which is preventing me to proceed forward.

Here is the question:
Convert built-in dataset VADeaths into dataframe-table VADeathRate with 3
columns (1st: ranges, 2nd: type of individual, 3rd: frequency). [do not
rename the column-names. They will be default as var1,var2,Freq]
Use the dataframe - VADeathRate to create bar plot based on Var1, Freq.
Split the layouts based on Var2 and plot it on the same single row layout.

I tried looking through manuals and course materials. Either i am not understanding the question rightly or there is some thing i am missing. The code i wrote is:

```
require(lattice) 
VADeathRate <- as.data.frame.table(VADeaths)
barchart(Freq ~ Var1 | Var2,data = VADeathRate,layout= 
(c(4,1)),xlab="Age Group",ylab="Frequency",col=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

[Output from R Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5jFA.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Even tried coding something like this with no luck. Would appreciate if someone can let me know what i am doing wrong:                                                  
require(lattice)
VADeathrate <- as.data.frame.table(VADeaths)
barchart(Freq ~ Var1| Var2, data = VADeathrate, 
         groups = Var2, besides=TRUE,layout = c(4, 1),
         auto.key = list(title = "Barchart", columns = 2))

Answer (score 0):

After many trail and error, i was able to figure the answer:

```
library(lattice)  VADeathRate <- as.data.frame.table(VADeaths)
barchart(Var1 ~ Freq | Var2, data = VADeathRate,
         groups = Var2, main = "Bar Chart in R EXample",
         ylab = "Var1",  stack = TRUE,
         auto.key = list(space = "right"),
         scales = list(x = list(rot = 45)),
         layout = c(4,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:-

```
library(lattice)
VADeathRate<-as.data.frame.table(VADeaths)
barchart(Var1 ~ Freq | Var2, data = VADeathRate, groups = Var2, auto.key = TRUE)
```